# Bootstrap Panel-body with table inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel that collapses it self closed on click of an icon. This panel contains a table inside that is full width but only looks this way when there is no `panel-body`.

For example, this table spans the full width and height of the panel, looks fine but I'd prever if I could have a class that surrounds the table. However, If I put something there, it adds padding to it:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover specialCollapse">
   ....
   </table>
```

This block of code has a class that surrounds the table, however it then adds padding to it and doesnt look the same:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
   <span class="MyNewClass">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover specialCollapse">
      ....
      </table>
   </span>
</div>
```

I wouldn't mind if I was able to use the original `panel-body` if it can be changed to have full width & height tables like the first block of code.

Here is a quick fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/z0y0hp8o/1/

This is the final result I want BUT, I need the table to be wrapped around a `panel-body` with no padding. ***This needs a new class though because other panels on the page need to act like normal.***

In short... I need a table to be full width and height when inside a `panel-body`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following styles in your custom css:

```
.table > thead > tr > th{
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:0;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td{
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table > thead > tr > th:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0px;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0px;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}

.panel-body > .table{margin-bottom:0px;}
```

**Fiddler:** http://jsfiddle.net/z0y0hp8o/6/

I hope the above solution will work for you.

Comment: This is very close, the table still has an outerborder on it that needs to be removed since the panel border acts as the border for the table.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and the answer. Please reply if you still have questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default stylesheet added by bootstrap for the panel body:

```
.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

So add your own css to replace the above with:

```
.panel-body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: There is then a bunch of other things it inherits such as a table margin, table borders etc that seemed to be ignored when a table is inside a panel directly. Just adding that bit of css doesn't fully fix what I need.

Comment: You wanted to remove the paddings around the table, isn't it? It does so.

Comment: That is correct, I also provided an example of the differences between the two. One of which (the one you kindly suggested) is not exactly what I was looking for. While yes, it moves the padding, the table does not act the same way (borders, margins, etc) when it's in a panel-body vs when its in just a panel.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z0y0hp8o/2/  - Using your provided code, the second panel doesn't look like the top one which is what I am trying to figure out. Somewhere in BS it adjusts the table when its inside `panel` differently than when its inside `panel-body` (not only the padding)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to remove the padding from every panel-body, ad an ID and remove the padding from it.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Title Here</div>
        <div id="tablePanelBody" class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover specialCollapse">
                <tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
#tablePanelBody {
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrnwfgp7/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the div with another table element, ugly solution but it works.

```
<table class="panel-body specialCollapse">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover goup">
  ...content
 </table>
</table>
```